# Get table from one frame HTML using Rcurl and XML

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rcurl

How I get one table that is generally from on search in http://portal.inep.gov.br/basica-censo-escolar-matricula

The table is within th frame.

I have to select the state that owns the data: e.g ACRE and click in "consultar"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `Selenium`

```
require(RSelenium)
appURL <- "http://portal.inep.gov.br/basica-censo-escolar-matricula"
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)

# find iframes
iframes <- remDr$findElements("css selector", "iframe")
iframes[[1]]$highlightElement() # visual check
remDr$switchToFrame(iframes[[1]])

# get Estado selections
webElems <- remDr$findElements("css selector", "#uf option")
estadoNames <- sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()[[1]]})
webElem <- webElems[[which(estadoNames == "ACRE")]]
webElem$clickElement()

# click the submit button
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "btnSubmit")
webElem$clickElement()

# find the table
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css selector",".Resultado")
webElem$highlightElement() # visual confirmation
tableHTML <- webElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]

remDr$close()
remDr$closeServer()
```

Answer (score 0):

That particular one is tricky.

[image]

When I right click on the IFRAME section and do an Inspect Element in Chrome, it looks like it's being generated in such a way that makes it difficult to programmatically obtain.

I could extract the table by right-clicking on the `<html xmlns="http://…` line, choosing "edit as html" then doing a select-all, copying & pasting into Sublime Text and saving as an HTML file (e.g: http://rud.is/dl/22872999.html).

You can do the same thing (a little easier IMO) in Firefox by right-clicking on the table-frame and doing a right-click/view-source, then copying & pasting that HTML into a text editor like Sublime Text and saving to an HTML file.

You should be able to operate on files saved that way with standard R table/XML extraction code.

It's far from an optimal solution, but it works. I'm hoping others have a more programmatic approach.